# Are there any shortsword treatises/sources?

Tags: sword

By shortsword, I mean ~40-80cm overall length (closer to 50-75cm).

Examples include "butterfly swords", "wakizashi", "gladius", and similar weapons.

Particularly, I am interested in the "model 1832 foot artillery sword", and similarly-shaped weapons.

What are the best sources for learning this type of shortsword, or options for other shortsword styles?

Comment: Speaking from personal experience, learning any sword style from the internet is a bad idea, however difficult it may be to find a real life coach.

Comment: There are *many* such treatises: e.g. https://smallswordproject.com/historic-texts/ http://www.thearma.org/manuals.htm

Answer (score 1):

There are manuals for European [smallsword](http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Category:Side_Sword), [arming sword](http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Category:Arming_Sword), [dussak](http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Category:Dussack), and [messer](http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Category:Messer)

Comment: Links are subject to rot. Could you describe each manual a little and add the authors/titles? Thank you.

Comment: @Sardathrion I am linking to lists of manuals to the best online source for them

Comment: I know what you are doing. However, links only answers are frowned upon because of link rot. If you want your answer to be a good one, please add more information in case the links go dead.

Comment: Noted. I will see what I can do.